# Is there a better way to remove all of the three buttons on the title-bar and remove the scroll-bar using Windows API?

Tags: c, winapi, button, console-application, mingw32

The code removing all of the three buttons on the title-bar and removing the scroll-bar I use in **"Windows 7"** so far is listed:

```
#define WINVER 0x0501 // WinXP and UP
#include <windows.h>

int main ( void ) 
{
     //Get a console handle
     HWND ConsoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();

     //Change Settings
     SetWindowLong (ConsoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, WS_THICKFRAME);
     SetWindowLong (ConsoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, WS_CAPTION);
     SetWindowPos  (ConsoleWindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

     //Resize
     system ("mode con cols=75 lines=50");
     system ("pause>nul");
     return 0;
}
```

Compiling Command:

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -c "Console_Graphing_10.c" -o "Console_Graphing_10.o"
mingw32-gcc.exe -o "Console_Graphing_10.exe"  "Console_Graphing_10.o"
```

But this cannot remove all of the three buttons on the title-bar and remove the scroll-bar in **"Windows XP"**

Is there any better code to achieve this goal? Thanks.

Comment: @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey Probably, Yes.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Any wizard? Please help me...

Comment: Would it satisfy to have them all greyed?

Comment: @ryyker I've already known how to have them all greyed. But... I just want to make them all being removed. :-)

Comment: I do not believe this is _possible_.  I really hate that word, and rarely use it, but according to [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7575720/645128), and the comment below it, by a very knowledgeable Windows person @Hans Passant, this is unfortunately the case.  By the way, I tried your code snippet, on Windows 7, it fails with -3 error code _File was not found._

Comment: @ryyker which is your compiler? GCC or MSVC?

Comment: @ryyker I pasted the complete code, and it can be compiled successfully.

Comment: @KVD - I am using an ANSI C compiler from National Instruments.  Posted an answer below that address OP issue (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#define WINVER 0x0501 // WinXP and UP
#include <windows.h>

int main ( void ) 
{
  LONG style;
  HWND ConsoleWindow;

  ConsoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();

  style = GetWindowLong(ConsoleWindow, GWL_STYLE); 
  style &= ~( WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU ); 
  SetWindowLongPtr(ConsoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, style);

  SetWindowPos(ConsoleWindow, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED |
  SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);

  system ("pause>nul");
  return 0;
}
```

all buttons will be removed:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but yours and mines are both not effective on WinXP

Comment: Still, it works perfectly on Win7, but not effective on WinXP.

Comment: @KVD I tried [Window Detective](http://windowdetective.sourceforge.net/) with XP's console, it's not able to do anything with the title bar. Please notify me back, I'll delete the post.

Comment: Me, too. This code is effective on win7, so you can just leave this post, :-)

Comment: Appreciate everyone's researching on this issue. :-)

Answer (score 1):

***I found This*** *after* my comment saying I thought it was not possible...

```
void ClearButtons(void)
{
    int index = WS_BORDER;
    unsigned int a = (unsigned int)((WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION) & (~WS_ICONIC));

    LONG_PTR lPtr;
    HWND hWnd = GetActiveWindow();
    lPtr = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, index); 
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, a);  
}
```

***Note:***  When compiling for 32-bit Windows, SetWindowLongPtr is defined as a call to the SetWindowLong function.  So, should work with either Windows 7, or with XP (did not test)

Test image:
[image]

Comment: THX, BUT MSVC? I tagged **GCC**.

Comment: I do not think it would matter.  If you are using Windows OS (i.e. creating and modifying panels on Windows 7) all you have to do in include the right #includes, and libs.  GCC will compile and build.  No?  I #included `#include <windows.h>` and `#include  ansi_c.h>`  And, no, I am NOT using MSVC.  I am using standard Windows API stuff from ***[HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***

Comment: Regarding _It didn't work on my GCC Compiler, so sad_.  If you include User32.lib, User32.dll and Winuser.h, it will build. (and probably clear the buttons)

Comment: THX. Well... I added `#include <ansi_c.h>`, but still got failed in `WinXP`.

Comment: Great. But it works perfectly on Win7, but not effective on WinXP. :(

Comment: @KVD -  Even after adding in the ***User32.lib*** and ***Winuser.h***?

Comment: YES... I have added those.

Comment: Okay, well, I am very sorry that I do not have an XP box to go any further.  Thanks for the good question though! +1 from me.  (Good luck)